# python Automating multifactor authentication

Tags: python, selenium, automation

code: driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='idSIButton9']").click()

complete error  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (805, 339). Other element would receive the click: 
(Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.80)

Comment: Add the `HTML` source for the element ? From the error `ElementClickInterceptedException` means another element is receiving the click, you can try click using near by element.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't just throw your error messages at us but give us a little explanation about what you want to achieve, your configuration, etc. At least, ask a concrete question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a little how-to. On the one hand, this will make it easier (or possible at all) for us to help you solve your problem, on the other hand it makes us feel less mis-used as robots...

Answer (score -1):

Another element is covering the element you are trying to click. You could use `execute_script()` to click on this.

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='idSIButton9']")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```